# What are the IIS server side consequences of an "Unclaimed" server push

Tags: asp.net, iis, http2, server-push

[HttpResponse.PushPromise](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn823340.aspx) perform a [HTTP/2 Server Push.](http://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#PushResources).

A common recommended use case is, during the serving of a html page, pushing secondary resources such as css, js or images.

So this works fine on an initial request, html is returned and all other resources over a single request/connection.

Now a secondary navigate occurs. The browser request the html and the server returns it, and also pushes the other resources. but the browser already has the other resources cached. These resources now move into a state of "Unclaimed pushed".

So what happens server side when an unclaimed push occurs?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell for sure what happens in the IIS implementation.

But the general logic is that the browsers see's the pushed stream (Push Promise frame) and recognizes it isn't interested in it. Therefore it sends a Reset frame for the stream to the server. The server the receives the reset frame for the stream which puts the HTTP/2 stream state for this pushed stream into the reset state. If there's still something writing to the pushed stream on the server it will fail due to this and the push will end.